# how to remove data from array in local storage?

Tags: javascript

How to remove particular data when user click on delete from array stored in local storage ?
the key named **title** and **description** in both data are stored in form of array.
this is my script file

```js
let title, description;

function validate() {
  title       = document.getElementById('title').value;
  description = document.getElementById('description').value;
  if (title == '') {
    alert("Please add title");

  } else if (description == '') {
    alert("Please add description");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myform").reset();
    console.log(title);
    console.log(description);
    store(title, description);
  }
}

function store(title, description) {

  // load the existing values (default to an empty array if not exist)
  let _title       = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("title") || "[]")
  let _description = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("description") || "[]")
  _title.push(title)
  _description.push(description)
  localStorage.setItem("title", JSON.stringify(_title))
  localStorage.setItem("description", JSON.stringify(_description))
  window.location.reload()
}

get_title       = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("title"))
get_description = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("description"))
let table1;
for (i = 0; i < get_title.length; i++) {
  if (get_title[i] == null) {
    console.log("null")
  } else {
    table1 += `
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">${i + 1}</th>
      <td id="tit">${get_title[i]}</td>
      <td id="descripti">${get_description[i]}</td>
      <td> 
        **
        <button type="button" 
             class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
             onclick="del(${i})">
          Delete
        </button>
        **
      </td>
    </tr>`
  }
}

document.getElementById('table1').innerHTML = table1;


function del(i) {
  localStorage.removeItem(`title[${i}]`)
  localStorage.removeItem(`description[${i}]`)
  window.location.reload()
}
```

please help me to remove this items.

Comment: You need to remove the item from the array and put the array back into localstorage.  It is no different than how you store the full array.

Comment: So in other words: copy your `store` function, and instead of `push`, remove the correct item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage and sessionStorage are both key, value storages where both key and value are strings.

You will have to read the arrays

```
let titles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("title"));
let descs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("descs"));
titles.splice(i, 1);
descs.splice(i, 1);
localStorage.setItem("title", JSON.stringify(titles));
localStorage.setItem("description", JSON.stringify(descs));
```

I would suggest you store a single array with objects inside like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify([{ title: 'title1', descirption: 'description1' }]));
```

Otherwise you risk to have the arrays length out of sync.
Then when you read the array:

```
let get_items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
...
get_items[i].title; //reads title
get_items[i].description; //reads description
```